# How to share Terraform variables across workpaces/modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

Terraform Cloud Workspaces allow me to define variables, but I'm unable to find a way to share variables across more than one workspace.

In my example I have, lets say, two workspaces:

- Database
- Application

In both cases I'll be using the same AzureRM credentials for connectivity. The following are common values used by the workspaces to connect to my Azure subscription:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret   = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  tenant_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to duplicate values (in my case I'll have probably 10 workspaces). 
Is there a way to do this?

Or the correct approach is to define "database" and "application" as a Module, and then use Workspaces (DEV, QA, PROD) to orchestrate them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terraform Cloud, the Workspace object is currently the least granular location where you can specify variable values directly. There is no built in mechanism to share variable values between workspaces.

However, one way to approach this would be to manage Terraform Cloud with Terraform itself. [The `tfe` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tfe/index.html) (named after Terraform Enterprise for historical reasons, since it was built before Terraform Cloud launched) will allow Terraform to manage Terraform Cloud workspaces and their associated variables.

```
variable "workspaces" {
  type = set(string)
}

variable "common_environment_variables" {
  type = map(string)
}

provider "tfe" {
  hostname = "app.terraform.io" # Terraform Cloud
}

resource "tfe_workspace" "example" {
  for_each = var.workspaces

  organization = "your-organization-name"
  name         = each.key
}

resource "tfe_variable" "example" {
  # We'll need one tfe_variable instance for each
  # combination of workspace and environment variable,
  # so this one has a more complicated for_each expression.
  for_each = {
    for pair in setproduct(var.workspaces, keys(var.common_environment_variables)) : "${pair[0]}/${pair[1]}" => {
      workspace_name = pair[0]
      workspace_id   = tfe_workspace.example[pair[0]].id
      name           = pair[1]
      value          = var.common_environment_variables[pair[1]]
    }
  }

  workspace_id = each.value.workspace_id

  category  = "env"
  key       = each.value.name
  value     = each.value.value
  sensitive = true
}
```

With the above configuration, you can set `var.workspaces` to contain the names of the workspaces you want Terraform to manage and `var.common_environment_variables` to the environment variables you want to set for all of them.

---

Note that for setting credentials on a provider the recommended approach is to set them in environment variables rather than Terraform variables, because that then makes the Terraform configuration itself agnostic to how those credentials are obtained. You could potentially apply the same Terraform configuration locally (outside of Terraform Cloud) using the integration with Azure CLI auth, while the Terraform Cloud execution environment would often use a service principal.

Therefore to provide the credentials in the Terraform Cloud environment you'd put the following environment variables in `var.common_environment_variables`:

- `ARM_CLIENT_ID`
- `ARM_TENANT_ID`
- `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`
- `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`

If you use Terraform Cloud itself to run operations on this workspace managing Terraform Cloud (naturally, you'd need to set this one up manually to bootstrap, rather than having it self-manage) then you can configure `var.common_environment_variables` as a sensitive variable on that workspace.

If you instead set it via Terraform variables passed into the `provider "azurerm"` block (as you indicated in your example) then you force any person or system running the configuration to directly populate those variables, forcing them to use a service principal vs. one of the other mechanisms and preventing Terraform from automatically picking up credentials set using [`az login`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/azure_cli.html). The Terraform configuration should generally only describe what Terraform is managing, not settings related to who is running Terraform or where Terraform is being run.

Note though that the state for the Terraform Cloud self-management workspace will include
a copy of those credentials as is normal for objects Terraform is managing, so [the permissions on this workspace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/access.html#managing-workspace-access-permissions) should be set appropriately to restrict access to it.

Comment: I won't be able to use Enterprise for my project, but that's ok. Your complement on the environment configuration was a great plus, I was just looking into it because I knew by looking at it that those configurations shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [variable sets](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-cloud-variable-sets-beta-now-available) to reuse variable across multiple workspaces